# Not able to display a simple static bar using Primefaces

Tags: primefaces, progress-bar

I'm trying to display a progress bar using primefaces, its a simple static bar. This happens in all browsers. Below is the code:

```
<p:column headerText="Your progress">
<p:progressBar id="prgBar" value="50" labelTemplate="50%" displayOnly="true"/>
</p:column>
```

Thank you for your time.